# Counting number of 1 bits in binary representation

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I tried with the below code to convert decimal input into its binary representation, and then to count the number of 1's in it

When I run the below code, there is no output and there are no errors reported:

```
function demo() {
    var arra, i, rem;
    var Input = document.getElementById('demo');
    arra = [
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    var x = 1;
    while (Input > 0) {
        rem = Input % 2;
        Input = (parseInt(Input / 2));
        if (rem > 0) {
            arra[i] = 1;
            i = i + 1;
        } else {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }

    while (x < 35) {
        if (arra[x] == 1) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "SOB Found";
            x = x + 1;
        } else {
            x = x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Phase</title>
    <script src="SOB.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="value" id="Input"   />
    <input type="submit"  value="submit"   onClick="demo()"  />
    <p id="output"> </p>
    <script src="SOB.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add a better title to your question and try to explain it better please. Also, you don't have an element with ID `demo`. Maybe you meant to do `document.getElementById('Input');`?

Comment: 'JavaScript code'? What's wrong with JavaScript code?

Comment: @putvande Yes I already adjust the document.getElementById('demo')   to be document.getElementById('Input') but still not finding what is wrong with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues, but you can do this with much less code by using the `.toString(2)` method:

```js
function demo() {
    // Get input value via value property and convert to number (+)
    var val = +document.getElementById("input").value;
    // Convert to binary representation:
    var bin = val.toString(2);
    // Count the number of 1 bits, by counting the number of 
    //    matches when looking for 1s:
    var ones = bin.match(/1/g).length;
    // Output results, using textContent, not innerHTML:
    document.getElementById("binary").textContent = bin;
    document.getElementById("ones").textContent = ones;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="value" id="input">
<input type="submit"  value="submit" onclick="demo()">
<p>
Binary: <span id="binary"></span><br>
One bits: <span id="ones"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code. `var Input` the way you have it is a DOM element which doesn't actually exist (`demo`) isn't in your HTML, you probably wanted to do `var Input = document.getElementById('Input').value;`
Next is that you didn't give `i` an initial value which makes the first `arra[i]` `undefined: 1` (or whatever value `Input` is at that time.
Third, an `Array` starts at the index `0`, so `var x` should be `0`.

To bring it all together it should be:

```
function demo() {
    var arra, i = 0, rem;
    //            ^ giving i initial value
    var Input = document.getElementById('Input').value;
    //                                   ^       ^
    arra = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    var x = 0; // start index is 0
    while (Input > 0) {
        rem = Input % 2;
        Input = (parseInt(Input / 2));
        if (rem > 0) {
            arra[i] = 1;
            i = i + 1;
        } else {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }

    while (x < 35) {
        if (arra[x] == 1) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "SOB Found";
            x = x + 1;
        } else {
            x = x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8L30znv0/)

This works, although I don't understand what the meaning is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an empty array, use the implicit casted to number value of the input, use all small letter variables and count all `1` in the array. Then make an output with the count.

```js
function demo() {
    var array = [], i = 0, rem,
        input = +document.getElementById('Input').value,
        count = 0;

    while (input > 0) {
        rem = input % 2;
        input = Math.floor(input / 2);
        array[i] = rem;
        i++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = count + ' found of 1.';
    console.log(array);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="value" id="Input"   />
<input type="submit"  value="submit"   onClick="demo()"  />
<p id="output"></p>
```